# How to schedule a custom Task object within an async block?

Tags: python, http, python-asyncio

I've developed the following prototype, towards a callbacks-based approach to using asyncio with HTTP ([HTTPX](https://www.python-httpx.org/async/)).

My idea with this prototype was to produce a generic "task chain" structure for Python asyncio. This introduces a generic 'task data source' class, e.g running an HTTP request, together with a generic 'task chain' class extending the "data source" class with an additional "input task" field, such that each task chain object would be activated one the provided input task is complete. Each task chain object may then produce a value that any later objects could use. A task chain may alternately produce some output or an event in a user interface.

For a purpose of sharing both the process state and output data of each link in the task chain, I've tried to reuse the `result()` field of an asyncio Task. In one approach - as below - it seems to almost work out. This example will define the initial data source class as subclass of `asyncio.Task`, with each data source initialized as to dispatch to the source's mid-level `run_process()` coroutine. The task chain class will then inherit this characteristic of the data source implementation. The implementing classes must each define a `process()` coroutine, such that will be called from `run_process()`. The `process()` coroutine should return the value that will be stored as the task's result value.

I'd also tried developing this prototype with futures. It seems to be closer to working out, when using Tasks. It seems to work - almost - in the implementation below. At least, this implementation does not deadlock.

When changing one line of code however, the limitations of this implementation might become more apparent.

With a later update, it seems that even this implementation is not altogether working out - as though a link is being skipped in the task chain.

I'm trying to diagnose those limitations, at what I think may be a question about scheduling for a custom task object.

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod
from typing import Callable, Mapping
from typing_extensions import Generic, TypeVar

import asyncio as aio
import httpx

import json
from urllib import parse

Ti = TypeVar("Ti")
To = TypeVar("To")

class DataSource(aio.Task, Generic[To], ABC):

    def __init__(self, loop = None, name = None, context = None):
        super().__init__(self.run_process(), loop = loop, name = name, context = context)
        aio._register_task(self)

    def __hash__(self):
        return object.__hash__(self)
    
    @abstractmethod
    async def process(self) -> To:
        raise NotImplementedError(self.process)
    
    async def run_process(self) -> To:
        loop = self.get_loop
        aio._enter_task(loop, self)
        try:
            if __debug__:
                print("in run_process %r" % self)
            return await self.process()
        finally:
            aio._leave_task(loop, self)
            aio._unregister_task(self)
        
    def __repr__(self):
        return "<%s at 0x%x>" % (self.__class__.__name__, id(self))
    
    def __str__(self):
        return repr(self)


class FutureChain(DataSource[To], Generic[Ti, To]):
  
    @property
    def  in_future(self) -> aio.Future[Ti]:
        return self._in_future

    def __init__(self, in_future: aio.Future[Ti], loop  = None):
        super().__init__(loop)
        setattr(self, "_in_future", in_future)
        in_future.add_done_callback(lambda ftr: ftr.get_loop().create_task(self.process()))


    async def run_process(self) -> To:
        if __debug__:
            print("run_process %r wait for input from %r" % (self, self.in_future))
        await self.in_future
        if __debug__:
            print("run_process %r dispatch" % self)
        await super().run_process()
    
    ## must be implemented in derived classes: process()

Tr = TypeVar('Tr')
 
class RequestBroker(Generic[Tr]):
    method: str
    url: str
    def __init__(self,method: str, url: str):
        self.method = method
        self.url = url

    @abstractmethod        
    async def dispatch_request(self) -> Tr:
        raise NotImplementedError(self.dispatch_request)

class BytesRequestSource(DataSource[httpx.Response], RequestBroker[bytes]):
    
    ## FIXME also support an encoding object
    default_encoding: str 
    
    def __init__(self, method: str, url: str, 
                 default_encoding: str = "utf-8",
                 loop = None):
        DataSource.__init__(self, loop)
        RequestBroker.__init__(self, method, url)
        self.default_encoding = default_encoding

    async def dispatch_request(self) -> httpx.Response:
        async with httpx.AsyncClient() as client:
            client_mtd: Callable[..., httpx.Response] = getattr(client, self.method.lower())
            return await client_mtd(self.url)

    async def process(self) -> bytes:
        if __debug__:
            print("process() for %r" % self)
        response = await self.dispatch_request()
        try:
            data = b''
            async for chunk in response.aiter_bytes():
                data += chunk
            encoding = response.charset_encoding or self.default_encoding
            if __debug__:
                print("done: %r" % self)
            return data.decode(encoding)
        finally:
            await response.aclose()


class ParseChain(FutureChain[bytes, Mapping]):
    async def process(self) -> Mapping:
        if __debug__:
            print("process() for %r" % self)
        rslt = self.in_future.result()
        if __debug__:
            print("parsing %r" % rslt)
        return json.loads(rslt)

class PresentationChain(FutureChain[Mapping, None]):
    async def process(self) -> None:
        if __debug__:
            print("process() for %r" % self)
        rslt = self.in_future.result()
        print("Response: %s" % str(rslt))

def run_example(mtd, req):
    loop = aio.get_event_loop_policy().get_event_loop()
    bytesource = BytesRequestSource(method=mtd, url=req, loop = loop)
    parser = ParseChain(bytesource, loop = loop)
    presenter = PresentationChain(parser, loop = loop)

    if __debug__:
        print("running request")

    # return loop.run_until_complete(presenter)
    return loop.run_until_complete(bytesource)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    REQ="http://ip.jsontest.com"
    print("Response: %r " % run_example("GET", REQ))
```

When called as in that example, beginning the task chain at the first object - the byte source - then the code presents almost an expected response at the last point, with approximately the following process:

1. The byte source task runs an HTTP request and returns the result bytes. The aio frameork then sets the return value of the task coroutine as the task's s result value
2. The bytes parser reads the byte sequence from the byte source task and returns a decoded object. The return value from the task coroutine will similarly become the task's result value, for the bytes parser
3. The presenter task reads the decoded object* and prints it to stdout, with a task result value of None

* ideally, but that's not what's happening in this example. The presenter task is receiving and presenting an unparsed string, though the parser task has in fact decoded the response bytes as a JSON mapping. This becomes apparent after an update to the example

```
running request
in run_process <BytesRequestSource at 0x1daa0384400>
process() for <BytesRequestSource at 0x1daa0384400>
run_process <ParseChain at 0x1daa0384f40> wait for input from <BytesRequestSource at 0x1daa0384400>
run_process <PresentationChain at 0x1daa0385000> wait for input from <ParseChain at 0x1daa0384f40>
done: <BytesRequestSource at 0x1daa0384400>
run_process <ParseChain at 0x1daa0384f40> dispatch
in run_process <ParseChain at 0x1daa0384f40>
process() for <ParseChain at 0x1daa0384f40>
parsing '{"ip": "zyx.yxz.yyz.xyz"}\n'
Response: '{"ip": "zyx.yxz.yyz.xyz"}\n'
```

I believe that that kind of works. However, when replacing this call from the example:

```py
    return loop.run_until_complete(bytesource)
```

... to instead use this call, in effect to begin the task chain at the end of the chain ...

```py
    return loop.run_until_complete(presenter)
```

then it appears that the top-level `presenter` never receives the initial HTTP response. Moreover, the updated code results in duplicate requests.

```
running request
in run_process <BytesRequestSource at 0x1a6d650c4c0>
process() for <BytesRequestSource at 0x1a6d650c4c0>
run_process <ParseChain at 0x1a6d650d000> wait for input from <BytesRequestSource at 0x1a6d650c4c0>
run_process <PresentationChain at 0x1a6d650d0c0> wait for input from <ParseChain at 0x1a6d650d000>
done: <BytesRequestSource at 0x1a6d650c4c0>
run_process <ParseChain at 0x1a6d650d000> dispatch
in run_process <ParseChain at 0x1a6d650d000>
process() for <ParseChain at 0x1a6d650d000>
parsing '{"ip": "zyx.yxz.yyz.xyz"}\n'
process() for <ParseChain at 0x1a6d650d000>
parsing '{"ip": "zyx.yxz.yyz.xyz"}\n'
run_process <PresentationChain at 0x1a6d650d0c0> dispatch
in run_process <PresentationChain at 0x1a6d650d0c0>
process() for <PresentationChain at 0x1a6d650d0c0>
Response: None
process() for <PresentationChain at 0x1a6d650d0c0>
Response: None
Response: None
```

I believe this may be due to the following, such that the task created under `add_done_callback()` might be producing and storing a value from `self.process()` independent to the `self` (custom Task) instance where this is called - i.e that the custom Task object is not in itself being updated for its value.

```
in_future.add_done_callback(lambda ftr: ftr.get_loop().create_task(self.process()))
```

I'm not exactly certain of how to schedule the custom task object, in itself. At least, the example will schedule a coroutine on the custom task object ...

For at least that aspect of the implementation, is there some way to schedule the task itself outside of a call like `loop.run_until_complete()`?

This does not work, as the task is not a coroutine:

```
# from the ctor, self being a custom Task object
in_future.add_done_callback(lambda ftr: ftr.get_loop().create_task(self))
```

Similarly, this does not work, as the task is not a callable:

```
# from the ctor, self being a custom Task object
in_future.add_done_callback(lambda ftr: ftr.get_loop().call_soon(self))
```

Now that this prototype may have produced a custom task object, how can that task be scheduled within its assigned loop, outside of `loop.run_until_complete()` etc?

Comment: Using a standard asyncio style would help.

Comment: I'm not sure what the standard would be, here. thx tho

Comment: From the docs for asyncio.Task: "Use the high-level asyncio.create_task() function to create Tasks, or the low-level loop.create_task() or ensure_future() functions. Manual instantiation of Tasks is discouraged."  Also this, from "Extending" asyncio: "asyncio.Future and asyncio.Task should be never created directly, please use corresponding loop.create_future() and loop.create_task(), or asyncio.create_task() factories instead."  I don't think they're kidding.  Subclassing Task looks like a real high-wire act.  There must be an easier way to do what you need.